# SSRS 2008 - 'Carriage Return' working intermittently

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a small 20-row table in my SQL08-R2 database that has an nvarchar(max) field. Within this field, I have written text with various CR/LF's (see image below):

[image: Sample text]

For some reason when I create an RDL file and drop this particular field in a 'table' within Reporting Services, sometimes the CRF/LF's display properly and sometimes they don't. I have been searching and troubleshooting for several hours now with no answers...

All the text is showing up but the line breaks work on some rows but not on others.

Any thoughts on how to get the line breaks to render properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks Cory for your response... it was close to what finally worked:

```
=Replace(Fields!Header01.Value, Chr(13) ,Chr(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work, but maybe you could try replacing the cell in your table that you dump the nvarchar(max) field into with an expression that replaces each occurrence of a newline or carriage return with `CHAR(10) & CHAR(13)`. Or maybe you need to do it the other way around: replace `CHAR(10)` with `vbLf` and `CHAR(13)` with `vbCr`:

```
=Replace(Fields!YourField.Value, VbCrLf, CHAR(10) & CHAR(13))
```

Or:

```
=Replace(Replace(Fields!YourField.Value, CHAR(10), VbLf), CHAR(13), VbCr)
```

I can't remember which works better, but I've had to do this before to help cleanse some user input. The behavior might be "intermittent" only because of the source of the data in the database. If they are copying and pasting from various applications on various operating systems, the linefeeds and carriage returns might look different or be non-existent.